# Accessing vector intrinsics in g++ without -mavx or other on?

Tags: gcc

I know I can use an attribute in gcc to convince it to compile a function for a specific architecture:

```
void __attribute__((target("avx"))) func(...) {
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the vector intrinsics for AVX inside that function, but unfortunately gcc required -mavx or -march=native or equivalent to be turned on for the whole program before it'll give access through the x86intrin.h header.  Is there a way to convince it that it's OK for me to use them in a particular function, or am I stuck compiling kernels separately and linking them in?